# How to access an object in every class of module? Python

Tags: python, object, python-2.7, module

I have a module with two classes.
I created the object `ip = IPDB(fork=True)` in the 1st class `PyrouteTwo` in `__init__`.
I have no problem to access this object in any method from the 1st class.
The problem is I can't use this object in the 2nd class of the module `ConfigApplier`.

Here is a fragment of the code. It'll be network configurator using netlink socket to communicate with the linux kernel. The object I created is netlink communication socket and I can create just one in application, so I can't create another in the second class.

```
class PyrouteTwo(Configurator):
    def __init__(self, inRollback=False):
        super(PyrouteTwo, self).__init__(ConfigApplier(), inRollback)
        self.runningConfig = RunningConfig()
        logging.debug("testmark.PyR2.init")
        self.ip = IPDB(fork=True)
        self.ipr = self.ip.nl

    def configureBridge(self, bridge, **opts):
        self.configApplier.addBridge(bridge)
        if bridge.port:
            bridge.port.configure(**opts)
            self.configApplier.addBridgePort(bridge)
        self.configApplier.setIfaceConfigAndUp(bridge)
        logging.debug("testmark.PyR2.confBridge..")
# !!! Here I can use the object with no problem.
        dev = self.ipr.link_lookup(ifname='em1')[0]
        logging.debug("pyroute2 link_lookup output: %d", dev)

...
class ConfigApplier(object):

    def _setIpConfig(self, iface):
        ipConfig = iface.ipConfig
        logging.debug("testmark.PyR2.ConfApplier.setIpConf.")
        if ipConfig.ipaddr:
            self.removeIpConfig(iface)
            ipwrapper.addrAdd(iface.name, ipConfig.ipaddr,
                              ipConfig.netmask)
            if ipConfig.gateway and ipConfig.defaultRoute:
                ipwrapper.routeAdd(['default', 'via', ipConfig.gateway])
# !!! But here I can't use it !!!
        dev = self.ipr.link_lookup(ifname='em1')[0]
        logging.debug("pyroute2 _setIpConfig output: %d", dev)
```

Error outhput is here:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/vdsm/supervdsmServer", line 98, in wrapper
    res = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/vdsm/supervdsmServer", line 190, in addNetwork
    return configNetwork.addNetwork(bridge, **options)
  File "/usr/share/vdsm/configNetwork.py", line 190, in wrapped
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/vdsm/configNetwork.py", line 290, in addNetwork
    netEnt.configure(**options)
  File "/usr/share/vdsm/netmodels.py", line 159, in configure
    self.configurator.configureBridge(self, **opts)
  File "/usr/share/vdsm/netconf/pyroute_two.py", line 73, in configureBridge
    self.configApplier.setIfaceConfigAndUp(bridge)
  File "/usr/share/vdsm/netconf/pyroute_two.py", line 257, in setIfaceConfigAndUp
    self._setIpConfig(iface)
  File "/usr/share/vdsm/netconf/pyroute_two.py", line 227, in _setIpConfig
    dev = self.ipr.link_lookup(ifname='em1')[0]
AttributeError: 'ConfigApplier' object has no attribute 'ipr'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `ConfigApplier` Class doesn't have the attribute `self.ipr`.  Your other class `PyrouteTwo` has `self.ipr` but not `ConfigApplier`.

I'm not sure what the intent of the code was, but you need to inherit from the `PyrouteTwo` class as a parent.  You're currently trying to use `super` to do that but it doesn't work that way.  You could also just merge the two classes into one.

You should try inheriting from `PyrouteTwo` but putting it in your initial class statement here:

```
class ConfigApplier(PyrouteTwo, object):
    #...
```

However, you could probably just add your only function in `ConfigApplier` to your `PyrouteTwo` class.  So just cut your `ConfigApplier` function and put it in `PyrouteTwo`.

If you have any questions ask below.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have to keep the structure of the module with 2 classes. It's big application and I'm trying to add just some functionality to it. 
When I tried class ConfigApplier(object, PyrouteTwo):, it responded with:
    TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
    Cannot create a consistent method resolution
    order (MRO) for bases object, PyrouteTwo

Comment: Try the updated post.  If that doesn't work, just try removing the `object` inheritance totally from `ConfigApplier`.

Comment: Thanks for the try, but it doesn't help. When I delete `object` from `ConfigApplier` inheritance, it won't run.

Comment: Did you try it the way it is in the updated post e.g. `class ConfigApplier(PyrouteTwo, object):`?

Comment: Yes, I writed you that in my first comment

Comment: Look closely, you need to switch the order of the items :)  Check my last comment and the post.